# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with spymemcached

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I'm getting this error trying to access a value on cache from a Web Service, but when I called the method directly on a test class it works fine.

some one got this error?

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/8z7bsDcc

I've try with it withour results: http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/issues/detail?id=155&colspec=stars%20id%20Milestone%20Priority%20Status%20Summary

Thanks.

Comment: What class is it complaining about? It should state it in the stacktrace. You can use it to find out what jar file may be missing from your Web servers classpath.

Comment: GRAVE: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wsrequest.transferws.ProductWSResponseResume
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question over here:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from every class every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284976/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-from-every-class-every-day/12573239#12573239)

It was related to the pom.xml and how resources were included.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you all required `jars` are available in webservice classpath.

You will get [ClassNotFoundException](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html) if required class is not available in classpath.