# Cannot Install Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

When I open the netbeans installer it shows a messagebox 

An error occurred while running java process
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main".

Am using jdk1.7.0
CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;

Comment: Have you check the MD5 checksum installer on your computer? Maybe the installer was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

For netbeans 7.4, PHP version, on debian, it needs java 7 jdk.

So I installed openjdk-7-jdk, as well as openjdk-7-jre, openjdk-7-jre-headleass,openjdk-7-jre-lib ;

And removed their counterpart 6 version (openjdk-6-jdk, openjdk-6-jre, openjdk-6-jre-headleass,openjdk-7-jre-lib ) .

Then I stumbled on :

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I removed useless packages

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Finally, I executed successfully the installer with the --silent option.

```
./netbeans-7.4-php-linux.sh --silent
```

And it worked.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from every class every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284976/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-from-every-class-every-day)

Does anything from this thread help? Perhaps you had a previous installation that wasn't cleared out properly?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem occurs when you have more than one version of IDE. What I recommend is to remove older version if you have or uninstall current version and try re-installing it again.