# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with NetBeans

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

Im getting this Exception with my project,after I run the project X times, I get it, but it is not always in the same class, sometimes it happens with other classes, or being more especific, with other frames, as far as I have seen, I have got it only with my frames.
when I get this error, I only retype the package of the frame that throws the exception and done!, but of course, that is not a solution.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xoxo/Vistas/VistaLogin$1
at xoxo.Vistas.VistaLogin.initComponents(VistaLogin.java:49)
at xoxo.Vistas.VistaLogin.<init>(VistaLogin.java:19)
at xoxo.Controlador.ControladorLogin.<clinit>(ControladorLogin.java:17)
at xoxo.princ.Principal.main(Principal.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xoxo.Vistas.VistaLogin$1
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 4 more
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `VistaLogin` in a separate project or library?  Have you tried clean and building the project?  Have your tried deleting the NetBeans cache?

Comment: same poroject, different package, clean and build gives a temporary solution, just like retyping the package. havent deleted the cache, how do I do it?

Comment: This happens mostly when the required class is not present aka dependency jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer of this i am sure that is Desired Solution. and if You sure 100% that there is exist same class which is shown in error.

[This is my ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284976/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-from-every-class-every-day/21302112#21302112)

Try it that will be helpful.