# Maven project in netbeans - how to rename a class from a dependency project?

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have a maven project called X and a second maven project called X-GUI.

As you can imagine X-GUI depends on X. In X i have a class which i want to rename. I refactor it, of course, every reference is renamed correctly in both projects.

Both projects compile without issues, the output jar contains the class with the new name, however when i run X-GUI it throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception`.

I tried deleting the NetBeans cache, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284976/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-from-every-class-every-day), also tried disabling the "Compile on Save" option (also mentioned in the above topic). Nothing works. When i rename the class back to the original name it works without any issues.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously you class is missing in jar file. Open jar file and ensure it is there.

Comment: Is it single jar?  Is it X-GUI project is separate jar file ? Is it in classpath when you start jar file? How do you run X-GUI ?

Comment: At least enter each project and execute mvn clean after you did rename class name

Comment: 1. Both projects compile just fine, the jar is there.
2. each project has its own jar file.
3. thats the first thing i did. 
I ran both projects in eclipse, sadly the situation is the same.Also the classpath seems just fine.

Comment: If some of class is not found then, IDE suppose to hightlight it as not existent import

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was related to the fact that the class i wanted to rename was static (final) and had a static block inside. I converted it to singleton and removed the static block and the problem has gone away.

I'd like to hear somebody's opinion on why would it behave like this?