# JAVA - com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

I'm working on an application that consumes a web service using SOAP requests.

Sometimes I get this error:

```
filters.LoggerFilter:92 - org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
```

The weird part is that I get this error randomly, but I can't seem to figure out the cause.

I even added a new dependency, but it doesn't seem to correct the issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: just suggestion : upgrade your **saaj-impl** version 1.3 to 1.4.0

Comment: @krezus already tried, still the same

Comment: probably about your  cache. which ide use ?please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284976/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-from-every-class-every-day)

Comment: @krezus thank you, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I checked the dependency cache (saaj-impl-1.3.jar) and there is no "internal" namespace. Strange

Comment: Hi, What JDK were you using?  Things change with Java 9 onwards

Answer (score 16):

I just had the same problem while using Java 11 to create an application that consumes SOAP-requests.

I added the new dependency and it worked fine for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I needed to add  -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl to the java command in Java 11

Answer (score 4):

For me, I was using Java 13 and the following worked for me(add these in the pom.xml)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried many things but this worked for java11

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day :) 
I just want to add that this config works for Java 13. But don't try to update versions of these packages! Just copy as it is with versions 2.4.4. Because newer packages not working for Java 13.

Answer (score 2):

For those who face this issue in intellij IDEA using Spring Boot under Java SDK 9+, you have to include explicitly `--add-modules java.se.ee` in VM parameters (edit configurations -> VM options). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) may help to resolve other importing issues related to new Java Modules

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
For me, adding saaj-impl was not enough to get rid of the exception

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I had to also add saaj-api which fixed it finally:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Since I realised that my application was using saaj-api 1.3.4 after checking with command, upgrading to 1.3.5 helped

> mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

Answer (score 1):

With open JDK 17 and spring boot 3.0.1, I was getting the same issue. It got resolved by adding these dependencies in pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
       <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your project sdk as Java 1.8

If you are using import javax.xml.ws library it could be confusing com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj dependency in Java 11. Clearing saaj dependency then using Java8 may be a solution in this issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this should solve the problem?

Comment: If you are using import javax.xml.ws library it could be confusing com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj dependency in Java 11. Clearing saaj dependency then using Java8 may be a solution in this issue

Comment: can you please add it as part of your answer?

Comment: I had the same problem with java 8, and is packaging my application as war and deploying to Tomcat 9. remove, if added, saaj-impl, saaj-api and jaxws-api from pom. and add cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs depedency. this should fix your problem. try doing pom-> maven-> reload project to be sure that jars are refreshed.