# cant open any files in netbeans 12.1

Tags: java, netbeans

so seemingly at random my netbeans just stopped working i have tried both reinstalling java and netbeans itself but nothing seems to work.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.lang.model.type.WildcardType starting from ModuleCL@187861c8[org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@49f6b559[org.netbeans.api.java], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@4769b07b, ModuleCL@184d45cd[org.netbeans.api.progress], ModuleCL@54066e7a[org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl], ModuleCL@2a170ce[org.netbeans.modules.projectapi], ModuleCL@303843f4[org.openide.text], ModuleCL@1a6b43b2[org.netbeans.modules.java.preprocessorbridge], ModuleCL@6b5e8159[org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing], ModuleCL@1657bb2f[org.netbeans.libs.lucene], ModuleCL@3aa16878[org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base], ...20 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.doFindClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:215)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/lang/model/type/WildcardType
    at org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.java.ui.RefactoringActionsProvider.canDelete(RefactoringActionsProvider.java:241)
    at org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.api.impl.ActionsImplementationFactory.doDelete(ActionsImplementationFactory.java:108)
    at org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.spi.impl.SafeDeleteAction.performAction(SafeDeleteAction.java:76)
    at org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.spi.impl.RefactoringGlobalAction.performAction(RefactoringGlobalAction.java:115)
    at org.openide.util.actions.NodeAction.performAction(NodeAction.java:270)
    at org.openide.util.actions.CallableSystemAction$1.run(CallableSystemAction.java:105)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$1.run(ActionInvoker.java:70)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.doPerformAction(ActionInvoker.java:91)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:74)
    at org.openide.util.actions.CallableSystemAction.actionPerformed(CallableSystemAction.java:102)
    at org.openide.util.actions.NodeAction.actionPerformed(NodeAction.java:258)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1012)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1056)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Possibly helpful to check if you have a cache or classpath problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284976/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-from-every-class-every-day#6560861

Comment: If you need help locating the cache, by default for newer versions of NetBeans, it is here: `C:\Users\<your_ID>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\<nb_version>`.